# gender count join query

Tags: join, count

I have three tables

```
Member - MemberID, gender, etc
Venue - VenueID, City, VenueName, etc
Event - EventID, EventDate, etc
```

Trying to display a query that shows the count of male and female for each event where the city is Glasgow and for the time period of January 2012.

My result so far is.

```
SELECT Venue.VenueName, Venue.City, Event.Eventdate, (select count(gender) from member where gender = 'm') AS MaleTotal, (select count(gender) from member where gender = 'f') AS FemaleTotal
FROM Venue INNER JOIN Event ON Venue.VenueID = Event.FKvenueID
WHERE Venue.City='Glagow' and Month(eventdate)=1 and year(partydate) = 2011;
```

This produces a table showing

```
VenueName-ABC Venue, XYZVenue;

City- Glasgow, Glasgow;

Partydate- 04/01/2012, 05/01/2012   

MaleTotal-4,4   

FemaleTotal-3,3
```

Which is wrong cause there is only a total of 7 entries in the member table and each only attending 1 event.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems you are missing the link between the event and the members. You need to consider that in your `male`/`female` results subquery. `(select count(gender) from member where gender = 'm' and memberId in (select memberId from members_events where members_events .eventID=Event.EventId)` where `member_events` is the table that holds the relationship between the members and the event they are registered in.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is a many to many relationship between members and events, you could try something like this

```
SELECT Venue.VenueName, 
       Venue.City, 
       Event.Eventdate,
       SUM (CASE gender WHEN 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MaleTotal, 
       SUM (CASE gender WHEN 'f' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FemaleTotal 
FROM Venue INNER JOIN 
     Event ON Venue.VenueID = Event.FKvenueID INNER JOIN
     Event_Member ON Event_Member.EventID = Event.EventID INNER JOIN
     Member ON Member.MemberID = Event_Member.MemberID
WHERE Venue.City='Glagow' 
  and Month(eventdate)=1 
  and year(partydate) = 2011
GROUP BY Venue.VenueName, 
         Venue.City, 
         Event.Eventdate
```